What is the connector name for this 820 μF 450 V Nichicon capacitor
I am trying to find a replacement for this capacitor taken from a Haier aircon unit fan motor circuit. The combination of specifications (μF, volts, size) are not currently listed on the Nichicon website, so I guess it was discontinued. The closest models I can find have a slightly different connector, meaning a similar replacement doesn't fit the PCB.
The markings are: Nichicon CE 105'C GG(M) 820 μF 450 V C1713 B17-037179
The GG(M) is the LGG range specified here, but they don't go up as high as 820 μF in 450 V, only to 680 μF.
The closest I can find specs-wise is in the next size down: LGL2W821MELC50 which I have purchased, but the “snap in” connectors are not the same.
I can't seem to find other connectors listed here which match the 90 degree turned style with the wider tabs and two prongs,
I've also looked through many suppliers like Mouser, Farnell, RS, etc. using the parametric search to find other connector names, but none seem to match this. The closest is the four-prong motor start caps.







I would simply call these a through-hole part, even if it is something different to a wire lead. It looks like there's traces of solder left up to a certain height that suggests it's previously been through-hole mounted. I looked on DigiKey and the closest description I would muster is 'Through Hole Radial, Can - Solder Lug', eg https://www.digikey.com.au/en/products/detail/nichicon/LKG1J682MKN/7698863 (although the lugs aren't at right angles and are a slightly different shape).

OK I see "solder lug" does seem closer. Yes it was through-hole mounted, which is the problem with the replacement part which doesn't fit the slots.  "lug" isn't an option on the Nichicon site, maybe they don't list all physical variants.

Datasheet: https://www.nichicon.co.jp/english/products/pdf/e-gg.pdf
Curiously, they don't catalog a 820uF 450V type [anymore?].  Pin type is "snap-in".  There is a note with a hyperlink, "The other terminal is also available upon request. Please refer page 272 for schematic of dimensions", here: 
https://www.nichicon.co.jp/english/products/pdf/e-term.pdf 
which specifies this as "vibration resistant".
Whether suppliers list them this way, is another matter.  You may have to check part numbers, photos and datasheets to be sure.  Yes, shopping for exact parts is sometimes a pain.

Ah right! I didn't see that note nor the hyperlink before. So it's "Snap in, Vibration-resistant type, Configuration code: EU"
